# How to return an IQueryable<Something> as an IQueryable<ISomething>

Tags: .net, linq, casting, interface, iqueryable

I have a class `Something` that implements `ISomething`.  How can I convert/cast from an `IQueryable<Something>` to an `IQueryable<ISomething>`.  When I try to cast, I am able to compile, but the result of the cast is always NULL.

Background:  The reason I am doing this is because my `Something` class is a CodeSmith-generated class (PLINQO template) that has table mapping decoration, methods, etc.  My `ISomething` interface is "POCO-style", in that it is dumb and simply mirrors the properties of the `Something` class.  It also exists in it's own namespace.  I am doing this so I don't have to reference the assembly that holds the `Something` class from my service layer.  The assembly that holds the `Something` class will only need to be referenced in my repository layer now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use LINQ method Cast

```
 IQueryable<Something> something = ...
 IQueryable<ISomething> casted = something.Cast<ISomething>();
```

Answer (score 11):

To understand what's going on here, it's important to look at this from the perspective of the type system.  To the type system, `Something` and `ISomething` are two types that have an inheritence-like relationship (implementation is not exactly inheritance, but close).  The  generic types `IQueryable<Something>` and `IQueryable<ISomething>` do not have this relationship.  They are two completely different types, and belong to a completely different part of the inheritance tree (the branch that includes IQueryable) than either Something or ISomething.

So when casting from `IQuerable<Something>` to `IQueryable<ISomething>`, as far as the type system is concerned you might as well try to cast from `IQueryable<double>` to `IQueryable<IDataRecord>`.  The result is the same: it doesn't know how to make that conversion, and so the `as` operator returns null.

One *solution* to this problem (not the problem itself, as indicated by others) called **covariance** is implemented in C# 4.0.  .Net Type Variance allows the type system to have a limited understanding of the *specialization* relationship between two different types that specialize the same generic type, so that when casting from one to the other the type can *vary* (note the root word here).

For code prior to .Net 4, you have to use something like the `.Cast<T>()` extension method.  But this is less ideal, because it forces a real cast operation, where type variance lets the framework use the actual type that's already there.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent explanation of the Covariance problem you are encountering in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494302/linq-casting-iqueryable-to-ilist-returns-null-why).

Answer (score 0):

Not how -- but rather, why:

Generic Covariance -- this link will help explain:

[C# Generic Covariance](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/10/26/c-generic-covariance/)

Comment: The explains the answer, not why the answer is needed.  And you'd do better linking to Eric Lippert's series on the topic.

Comment: @Joel:  Do you have a link to the series, by any chance?

Comment: There's not one good link I can give for the whole series.  I know there's an index on this StackOverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184551/difference-between-covariance-contra-variance/2556675#2556675