# C#: Semantics for generics?

Tags: c#, generics, semantics

I have a list:

```
private readonly IList<IList<GameObjectController>> removeTargets;
private readonly IList<IList<GameObjectController>> addTargets;
```

`PickUp` inherits from `GameObjectController`. But when I try this:

```
public IList<PickUp> Inventory

// ... 

gameObjectManager.MoveFromListToWorld(this, user.Model.Inventory);

// ...

    // This queues everything up to be removed, until ProcessMoves...() is called
    public void MoveFromWorldToList(GameObjectController removedFromWorld, IList<GameObjectController> addTarget)
    {
        toBeRemoved.Add(removedFromWorld);
        addTargets.Add(addTarget);
    }

// ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all the GameObjects on which removal is requested from the world.
    /// </summary>
    public void ProcessMovesFromListToWorld()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < toBeAdded.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObjectController moved = toBeAdded[i];
            addGameObjectToWorld(moved);

            if (removeTargets[i] != null)
            {
                removeTargets[i].Remove(moved);
            }
        }
        toBeAdded.Clear();
        removeTargets.Clear();
    }
```

I get a compiler error:

> cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList<PickUp>'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList<GameObjectController>'

Why does this occur? Shouldn't this be fine, since `PickUp` is a subclass of `GameObjectController`? Do I need something like Java's `Map<E extends GameObjectController>`?

Earlier, I was having a similar problem, where I was trying to implicitly cast `inventory` from an `IList` to an `ICollection`. Is this the same problem?

Comment: Signature of `MoveFromListToWorld`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my other answer here:
[How to return an IQueryable<Something> as an IQueryable<ISomething>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586705/how-to-return-an-iqueryablesomething-as-an-iqueryableisomething/2586805#2586805)

Short version:

Remember that `IList<PickUp>` and `IList<GameObjectController>` are two (and only two) completely different classes in the type system.  The only inheritance relationship they have comes from the System.Collections branch of the inheritance tree; there is none at all on the GameObjectController branch of the inheritance tree.  You might as well try to cast an `IList<double>` to an `IList<ArgumentNullException>`.

What you can do instead is call the `Cast<T>()` extension method that is available for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert `List<BaseClass>` to `List<DerivedClass>`.  Here is [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640738/c-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listproduct-to-listiproduct/2640776#2640776) that deals with this issue.

Comment: Well, you can convert it if you write code to do so - you just can't cast it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [co- and contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174%28VS.80%29.aspx) and is first supported in c# 4.0. And even then it only works with IEnumerable and not IList.

Comment: covariance is the name of one possible solution (which won't work here), not the name of the problem.

Comment: Its the heart of the problem.

Comment: no, it's not.  Covariance means a type is allowed to vary (note the root word) in a certain way.  _Invariance_ -- or the inability for a type to vary -- is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Well this is a bit philosophic ... You can either see "what he cannot do" (covariance) or "what is preventing him to do so" (invariance) as the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A list of base objects can certainly hold items of derived objects. What I cannot gather from your code, however, is exactly what you're doing. You have an `IList<IList<class>>`, and then the implementation of your method is not visible to us. But code like the following certainly works (Bar extends Foo)

```
IList<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
IList<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>() { new Bar(), new Bar() };
foreach (Bar bar in bars)
    foos.Add(bar);
```

Maybe you're trying to the below scenario? This is where you have a list of lists of base ofjects and a list of lists of derived objects? If so, you can cast like below.

```
IList<IList<Foo>> listOfFoos = new List<IList<Foo>>() { foos };
IList<IList<Bar>> listOfBars = new List<IList<Bar>>() { bars };

foreach (IList<Bar> b in listOfBars)
{
    listOfFoos.Add(b.Cast<Foo>().ToList());
}
```

Comment: That is correct. I am trying to do the above. How do I want to be doing this?